# Sitecore Powershell script to filter the users based on custom roles

Tags: powershell-extensions

we have custom roles in sitecore role manager and assigned them to sitecore users.

I am writing a Sitecore PowerShell script to filter the users based on my custom role 'Buyer'. below is my script. i am unable to filter users when i add the MemberOf to my script. Line #6, Line #12 not working. Please

```
$property = @(
@{Name='Email';Expression={ $PSItem.Profile.GetCustomProperty('email_address') }},
@{Name='FirstName';Expression={ $PSItem.Profile.GetCustomProperty('first_name') }},
@{Name='LastName';Expression={ $PSItem.Profile.GetCustomProperty('last_name') }},
@{Name='User Name';Expression={ $PSItem.Profile.GetCustomProperty('User Name') }},
@{Name='Roles';Expression={ $PSItem.MemberOf }} ########### NOT WORKING
)

# Gets not disabled users, next select all custome properties and save all properties to CSV file
Get-User -Filter 'Sitecore\*'  `
    | Where-Object { $_.Profile.State -ne 'Disabled' }
        `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf ########### NOT WORKING
            `|  Select-Object -Property $property `
                | Export-CSV -Path "$apppath\sitecore-enabled-uc.csv" -notype -encoding "unicode" 
           
Download-File  "$apppath\Sitecore-enabled-uc.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of users in a specific role by using the Get-RoleMember command, then you can iterate through the list returned.

```
$users = Get-RoleMember -Identity 'Buyer'
foreach($user in $users)
{
    Write-Host $user.Profile.UserName
}
```

The documentation for the command https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/security/get-rolemember

You can try running the following script to export the data:

```
 $Report = @()
    $ExportPath = "C:\Temp\sitecore-enabled-uc.csv"
    $items = Get-RoleMember -Identity 'Buyer'
    foreach($item in $items)
        {
            $roles = $item.MemberOf
            $roleNames = ''
            $roles | ForEach-Object -Process { $roleNames = $roleNames + $_.Name + ' ' }

            $reportItem = [PSCustomObject]@{
                        "Email"= $item.Profile.GetCustomProperty('email_address')
                        "FirstName"= $item.Profile.GetCustomProperty('first_name')
                        "LastName"= $item.Profile.GetCustomProperty('last_name')
                        "User Name"= $item.Profile.GetCustomProperty('User Name')
                        "Roles"= $roleNames
                }
                $Report += $reportItem
        }
       $Report | Export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path $ExportPath -force
```

Comment: Thank you Cristi, Can you please help me to modify my script Line #6, #12. i have given the script in my question. i am generating a report.

Comment: I posted the modified script in the latest answer edit