# Getting Sitecore Users faster, filtering based on custom property

Tags: sitecore-api, user-management, user-profile

Need help with the performance issue with sitecore GetUsers Function.

I have 80K sitecore users, and have custom property called "Accounts Assigned" in user profile. I am using pipe delimited in the "Accounts Assigned" property. example: 25909|25920|25670|25089

we are using this query to report the users assigned to particular Account.

```
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserManager.GetUsers().Where(x => x.Profile.GetCustomProperty("Accounts Assigned").Contains("25909"));
```

This is taking 140 seconds, is there a way to remediate that function,

Comment: How often do account assignments change, is adding caching an option?

Comment: users can request change to their profile from website, so to answer your question assignments can change very frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore user management is based [ASP.Net Membership](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-aspnet-membership-provider). ()

The architecture of ASP.Net membership wasn't designed to perform operations that you try to do quickly. How your code will work internally:

1. It will get all users (80K)
2. It will deserialize all profiles (Profiles are saved in a separate table. They are saved in the serialized way for flexibility to add any properties without changing database structure. It causes a trade-off: you can't add database index and quickly query  profiles directly from database) (80K)
3. It will get profile property "Accounts Assigned" for each user (80K)
4. It will run .Net search inside string on required value. (80K)

I suggest you rethink your architecture and save values that you need to query in another place. It could be:

- Cache
- Index
- Database (with a proper scheme for quick access)

P.S. I assume that you don't use Sitecore Identity Server as it wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks Anton. it is Sitecore commerce website. so I think Sitecore uses Identity server. but I am not sure how that information is stored in Identity server and retrieve that information from there. please let me know if there is a way to retrieve information from identity server.
Just for your information: I can see all the users from the aspnet_Membership, aspnet_Profile, aspnet_UsersInRoles, & aspnet_Users tables in sitecore core database.

Comment: Anton, here is what I have in user profile caching.

Step 1 Value: 
              UserProfileCache 15 18.3 KB 18.3 KB 5 MB
Step 2 Value:
              <setting name="Caching.UserProfileCacheSize" value="5MB"/>

Comment: That is very strange: It cached only 15 user profiles and took 18KB total. I expect that there should be 80K records, one per user.

Comment: As it takes about 1 KB for 1 user profile, you will need 8000KB = 8MB for caching. (otherwise, the cache would not work properly, it will be rewritten all the time)

Comment: I suggest you update Caching.UserProfileCacheSize setting and set it to at least 20MB to have some margin of safety.

Comment: I have 3 Display Servers, and they are load balanced, i see different data in all the servers.
second Display I have like this: UserProfileCache 159 165 KB 165 KB 5 MB
third Display I have like this: UserProfileCache 600 620 KB 620 KB 5 MB
still it is strange where I do not have all the users in UserProfileCache.

how can I use identity sever to pull that information. see my first comment.

Comment: @Shrad Sorry for misleading you. I looked at how UserProfileCache is working. Sitecore evicts entries for a user from the UserProfile cache when a user logs in or logs out. It means that Sitecore doesn't leverage caching for the code that you use. That is why you need to implement your own caching. Answer was updated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead can use `Domain.GetDomain("domainName").GetUsers()` which is much faster than `UserManager.GetUsers()`.

For reference, please have a look at below attached url

https://sitecorecontextitem.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/get-all-sitecore-users-by-domain/

Comment: Thanks gupta, I am having a performance issue on applying the filter on the custom property, not on getting all the sitecore users.
here is my filter linq query:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.Where(x => x.Profile.GetCustomProperty("Accounts Assigned").Contains("25909"));

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own Caching (either sitecore custom cache if you want to see it also on the `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx` page or application cache) for the list of users returned by your query, this way you would only run the query once. Then when users are requesting changes to their profile in the website you also add/remove them from the cache created previously.

Where are you using the result of the user query? Are you calling this query in author environment only or also on the public website?

Depending on how and where you are using the list of users and if powershell is installed in your Prod environment you can run a script in your code as described in the post https://blog.najmanowicz.com/2012/04/06/using-powershell-console-for-sitecore-in-your-own-code/. The script would be similar to the one you asked in [Sitecore Powershell script to filter the users based on custom roles](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27634/sitecore-powershell-script-to-filter-the-users-based-on-custom-roles).

Comment: Thank you Cristi,
I am using on public website, where company admin(role) of that account can manage the users of his company account.